# Unresolved Identifier - Objective-C Pod in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, bridging-header

I have followed all instructions to install an Objective-C pod into my Swift project. I made a bridging header that IS being found upon build, but I cannot access any of classes. The bridging header path is relative to srcroot so I am not worried about the file being found.

I imported my pod in the bridging header like so:

```
#import <ASCFlatUIColor/ASCFlatUIColor.h>
```

I have already looked here: [How to call Objective C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift), but I am still getting errors from:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = ASCFlatUIColor.emeraldColor()
```

I have no errors in the pod, but my project simply is not capable of finding the pod's files:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'ASCFlatUIColor'
```

Do I have to add any user header search paths?

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so I found the fix. Make sure to link the framework in "Link Binary with Libraries":

[image: Link Binary With Libraries Screenshot]

After you do that, you can add an import statement:

```
import ASCFlatUIColor
```

And then you have access to:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = ASCFlatUIColor.emeraldColor()
```

Hope this helps someone else!